# SQL Server convert to optimal short date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the most optimal short date to convert  to in SQL Sever to use in a predicate.

I have a date `2013-06-11 15:06:27.000` and want to use the short date part `2013-06-11` in a predicate.

What would be the best short date to convert to in SQL Server for this purpose?

[MSDN - Date convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: What version of SQL Server? For 2008 or later, just `CONVERT(date,<Column>)` should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL2005+:

**Note:** `Select Convert(DateTime, Convert(VarChar, DateTimeColumn, 12)) <operator> <const>` isn't `SARG`able! So, if you have an index on `DateTimeColumn` then SQL Server can't seek (`Index Seek`) on this column. Instead, SQL Server will use an `Index Scan`, `Clustered Index Scan` or `Table Scan`.

If you want to filter rows on a `DATETIME` column you could use `DateTimeColumn >= RangeStart AND DateTimeColumn < RangeEnd`or `DateTimeColumn BETWEEN RangeStart AND RangeEnd` predicates.

How can be generated `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` ?

```
    DECLARE @SelectedDate DATETIME;
    SET     @SelectedDate='2013-06-11 15:06:27.000';

    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@SelectedDate),0) AS Start,
            DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@SelectedDate)+1,0) AS [End 1],
            DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@SelectedDate)+1,0)) AS [End 2]
```

**Note 2**: For `DATETIME` column, the last millisecond can be one of these `{0,3,7}` (see [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)).

Results:

```
Start                   End 1                   End 2
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2013-06-11 00:00:00.000 2013-06-12 00:00:00.000 2013-06-11 23:59:59.997
```

Example #1:

```
...
WHERE   h.OrderDate>=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@SelectedDate),0)
AND     h.OrderDate<DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@SelectedDate)+1,0)
```

Example #2:

```
...    
WHERE   h.OrderDate>=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@SelectedDate),0)
AND     h.OrderDate<=DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@SelectedDate)+1,0))
```

Example #3:

```
...
WHERE   h.OrderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@SelectedDate),0) AND DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@SelectedDate)+1,0))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Select Convert(DateTime, Convert(VarChar, GetDate(), 12))
```

Comment: This formula sorted the results correctly by the query and excel. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

not really that hard, if you are using sqlserver 2008+

```
cast(@date as date)
```

or

```
convert(date, @date)
```

Since you are using sqlserver 2005

```
CONVERT(CHAR(10), @date, 121)
```

However if you are going to compare with another date, keep the datetime format and remove the time part:

```
dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, @date))
```

Comment: I get `Type date is not a defined system type.`

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(12),GETDATE(),12)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a SQL Server version prior to 2008 then I would use the following method:

```
SELECT DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, Current_Timestamp), 0);
```

The reason I would chose this method over the others suggested is that it avoids casting to a character datatype (and back).

You may also chose to use this method for versions after and including 2008 depending on what you intend on doing to this value... If you're going to compare it to another `datetime` value, then this method will at least retain the same data type for comparison. If it is to compare against a `date` value then used the aforementioned `SELECT Cast(Current_Timestamp As date);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 select    FORMAT( getdate(),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```